# jQuery form plugin, ajaxForm() but with conditional fields

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-forms-plugin

I need to upload a form with ajaxForm() (or so I believe, as fieldSerialize() doesn't seem to serialize file fields properly).

How can I only serialize a subset of the fields in my form using ajaxForm() ? I've tried manipulating the arr or $form parameters in beforeSerialize() or beforeSubmit() but it doesn't do it.

OR how can I use ajaxSubmit() or fieldSerialize() so that it supports file upload files as well. Lets say for EG I want to just exclude fields with the class hiddenField on it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wouldn't simply setting the unwanted fields to disabled solve this?

I believe disabled fields are not submitted. See this in the jquery source code>

```
serializeArray: function() {
    return this.map(function(){
        return this.elements ? jQuery.makeArray( this.elements ) : this;
    })
    .filter(function(){
        return this.name && !this.disabled &&
            ( this.checked || rselectTextarea.test( this.nodeName ) ||
                rinput.test( this.type ) );
    })
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer, the problem is thats not a part of the jQuery form plugin, but jquery itself, I need to operate within the plugin as it has upload functionality http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#getting-started

Comment: Ah turns out the form plugin also ignores disabled fields :) Thanks for your brain wave.

Answer (score 0):

Write a custom serialize function like this one: Note jQuery will filter out any input with 'hiddenField' class attribute value

```
  function scrapeFormData(formName){
var frm_data = "";
$('#'+formName+' :input').not('.hiddenField').each(function(){
    switch(this.type){
        // handle checkbox specially 
        // I persisted my checkbox field this way. You can do this in a better way
        case 'checkbox': {
                if ($(this).attr('checked') == 'checked'){
                    frm_data += $(this).attr('id') + "=1&";// checked value 1
                }else{
                    frm_data += $(this).attr('id') + "=0&";// unchecked value 0
                }
                break;
        }
        // handle radio button specially
        // I persisted my radio button field this way. You can do this in a better way
        case 'radio': {
                if ($(this).attr('checked') == 'checked'){
                    //alert('checked');
                    frm_data += $(this).attr('id') + "=" + $(this).attr('value')+"&";
                }                   
                break;
        }
       default:{
                frm_data += $(this).attr('id') + "=" + $(this).attr('value')+"&";
                break;
        }
    }
});   
frm_data = frm_data.substring(0,(frm_data.length - 1));
return frm_data;
```

}